# Schedule periodic mysql script to run automatically every hour

Tags: mysql, database, automation, mysql-workbench, sql-scripts

I've been searching, but nothing clear came up.

I wonder if there is a way to schedule a big MYSQL script which takes normally up to 2 minutes to run (with workbench not able to run in phpmyadmin cause of timeout -> server not in my hands) so that it would automatically run every hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just to clarify, MySQL Workbench is a native application. It cannot run **in** PMA or any other web application.

MySQL Workbench itself (or MySQL for that matter) does not have a scheduler or something like that. You can however use your OS' means. E.g. use AT or crontab to run MySQL Workbench and pass it the script to execute. Run MySQL Workbench from the commandline with the -h (or --h on non-Win) switch to get a list of possible parameters.